# Display monitor with fast Boot-up / Picture-on time

Tags: television, hdtv

I need recommendations for a cheap display monitor for use in CCTV door access.

To save electricity the monitor will remain powered off at all times, until somebody needs to answer the front door and manually switches on the display monitor. It is crucial, therefore, that the chosen monitor is able to display video extremely quickly from the moment it is powered on.

- Approximate screen size: 14"
- Type / Format: HD LED wide screen
- Market: Either new or used.

Video input will be from an IP CCTV camera via its local BNC / phono output.

BTW, I found it impossible to construct a search query for this question on Google.

Thanks for any helpful assistance.

**20/12/2019 - Update**

I've discovered the Samsung SMT-1935 is made for the CCTV market, used monitors are available cheaply, but I'm having difficulty persuading sellers to check the power-on time with a BNC feed.

Comment: An LCD panel that has LVDS (like a laptop replacement screen) and a separate driver board might be faster than an off-the-shelf consumer monitor. It seems like laptop screens are much faster than desktop monitors, probably because the video input is always active and there is no need for a handshake to start the video stream every time the laptop lid is opened. You will also need some kind of adapter to convert the CCTV video signal to whatever the input on LCD driver board is, unfortunately that adapter may introduce a delay...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution to the problem which is to have the monitor powered by a PIR motion sensor located outside above the front door.